# Stripe custom form with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, stripe-payments

While creating custom form, on submission you are required to send the form to the server. This is quite simple with DOM selectors. Here:

```
var $form = $('#payment-form');
Stripe.createToken($form, this.stripe_response_handler);
```

However one should not directly try to modify or access DOM when using React. To overcome this, I used `ref`. Here:

```
<Form onSubmit={this.select_plan} ref={(ref) => this.paymentForm = ref} >
...
</Form>
```

and then

```
Stripe.createToken(this.paymentForm, this.stripe_response_handler);
```

However this resulted in error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

What is the correct way of doing this in React?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are several ways how you can use `Stripe.js`, you can pass form `DOMElement` (and you don't need use `ref`, because you can get form element from `e.target` in `onSubmit` event) where there are data attributes for `Stripe`

```
var StripeComponent = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function () {
    Stripe.setPublishableKey(); // set your test public key
  },

  handleSubmit: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Stripe.card.createToken(e.currentTarget, function (status, response) {
      console.log( status, response );      
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return <form method="post" onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
      <input size="20" data-stripe="number" placeholder="number"/>
      <input size="4" data-stripe="cvc" placeholder="cvc" />
      <input size="2" data-stripe="exp-month" placeholder="exp-month" />
      <input size="4" data-stripe="exp-year" placeholder="exp-year" />
      <button type="submit">Pay</button>
    </form>;
  }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/24422/)

or you can create custom data object like this

```
var StripeComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      card: {
        number: '',
        cvc: '',
        exp_month: '',
        exp_year: ''
      }
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
    Stripe.setPublishableKey(); // set your test public key
  },

  handleSubmit: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Stripe.createToken(this.state.card, function (status, response) {
      console.log( status, response );
    });
  },

  handleChange: function (e) {
    let card = this.state.card;
    card[e.target.name] = e.target.value
    this.setState(card);
  },

  render: function() {
    return <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
      <input size="20" name="number" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <input size="4" name="cvc" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <input size="2" name="exp_month" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <input size="4" name="exp_year" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <button type="submit">Pay</button>
    </form>
  }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/24423/)

**Note** - *To test examples you need set public key*

Comment: worked perfectly! thanks a lot. :) Again sorry for delayed response.